# How can I detect if the webpage is being rendered in WebBrowser Control?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webbrowser-control

Most of the people who will access my app will do so from a preinstalled software on their pc that has a browser component built with Microsoft's [WebBrowser Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040(v=vs.85).aspx) which is just Internet Explorer wrapper.

I want to know if there's a way I can detect, using Javascript, or any other method from inside my website, when it is being rended using this wrapper.

The reason I want to do this is that software was already built and goes to the home page of my site. But I want to redirect them directly to the login screen if they are accessing from that wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

By default the WebBrowser Control uses IE7 so you can check the [user agent string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (I doubt your other users will be using such an old Internet Explorer version as their browser causing a faulty recognition).

However, this is not a perfect solution, if you can modify the preinstalled software and deliver a new version to people that will be using it you can send a specific header along with the request to determine its origin.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this accurately.  As Samuil stated, you can hack it a bit and maybe catch some of it.

Why not set the default page of your website to be the login page so the user goes to that page regardless?